# How to insert a list of States in Salesforce with the Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, country-and-state

Is it possible to insert a list of States in Salesforce with the Metadata API?
[image]

How?

Thank you very much.

---

**Additional Question** (02-June-2021@12:11CEST):

I have retrieved the XML file containing the list of States/Countries (it is now stored in C:...\TEST1\force-app\main\default**settings**\

The file name is **Address.settings-meta.xml**

I have copied/past this file into another sub-directory where I keep a copy of the code of the "Destination Org called DEV1: ...\DEV1\force-app\main\default**settings**\

I was expecting to be able to deploy the XML file with Visual Studio Code + SFDX CLI but, the deployment is not successful: I get an error without details.

Then, I try to deploy the same xml file with Workbench. The deployment is apparently successful BUT when I go to that Org to verify if the States have been deployed... I observe they a have NOT been deployed.

Any input that might help me?

Thank you.

Comment: I had to do this recently and used this [open-source tool](https://github.com/mattandneil/statecodes).  It worked well but took 10 hours to complete.  I'm not affiliated with the authors.

Comment: @DavidCheng Ten hours? That seems... excessive.

Comment: @DavidCheng: thank you!